# Authentication failed in laravel test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-6, jenssegers-mongodb

I'm trying to write  a test  but I can't authenticate with a fake test user, I'm using `mongodb`,  `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` and `jwt-auth`

this is the factory I've created

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$factory->define(\App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'username' => $faker->name(),
        'password' => $faker->password()
       
    ];
});
```

phpunit.xml file

```
<php>
  <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
  <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
  <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
  <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mongodb"/>
  <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
  <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
  <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
  <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
</php>
```

this is the test

p

```
ublic function test_if_can_customer(){
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $user = User::factory()->make();

        $url = '/customer/12345646';
        $response = $this->actingAs($user,'api')
                         ->json('GET', $url);
    
        $response
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJson([
                'meta'=>[
                    'success'=>true
            ]
       ]);
}
```

and I get this error:

```
1) Tests\Feature\LeadTest::test_if_can_get_customer
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

UPDATE:

If I use sqlite instead of mongodb

```
<php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    </php>
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::__construct() must be an instance of Jenssegers\Mongodb\Connection, instance of Illuminate\Database\SQLiteConnection given, called in /home/myuser/myproject/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Eloquent/Model.php on line 415
```

Comment: For genetal testing, you should use the SQLite connection. In case you want to actually interact with your Mongo driver, you could create a separate database and specify it in your phpunit.xml

Comment: Your test never run because the connection to the database is failing. (MongoDB needs a username and password but you didn't specify it in your phpunit.xml). I agree with the comment above, you should use SQLite for testing instead of mongoDB in your phpunit.xml, then you don't need a username/password.

Answer (score 0):

Your factory and test code never run because the connection to the test database is failing. It's failing because MongoDB needs a username and password but you didn't specify it in your `phpunit.xml`.

However, like Kenny Horna said in his comment above, you should use SQLite for testing instead of mongoDB.

In your `phpunit.xml`, change your `DB_CONNECTION` to `sqlite`:

```
  <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
```

Comment: I get an error I use `sqlite` I've updated the question

Comment: Looks like an issue with your package `Jenssegers\Mongodb`. Did you properly configure your `config/database.php` and `.env` files with your credentials?

Comment: I think its correct becaus te app  works , the problem its only ton testing using sqlite

Comment: The problem is your testing setup is not properly configured. It's calling `Jenssegers\Mongodb` without the proper credentials. Instead it should call SQLite. Check you configuration files.